# Can I force a password change?

Tags: security

When I create a new user, I would like to force that user to change their password on first log in, can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, but you could implement it by:

Adding a user meta on user create.

Dropping that meta on user password update.

Redirecting the user to his profile page, from anywhere else, if the user meta is around.

Comment: what methods could help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this as well. My theme presently sends out an auto password. Would like to find a way to force a password change upon first time login

Comment: This is very simple to do. 1. remember the user's account email address in the Users panel of the site and change their password to something random and save it. 2. Log yourself out of the WP Dashboard. 3. Now at the login window look for the "Lost your Password?" link, click it. 4. Enter the user's email address that you would like to reset. 5. They will receive an email telling them that a password reset has been performed on their account and if they attempt to login with their old password, they can't and will have to choose a new one.